# How to use fading text and CTA for content block?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogs

I don't want people to have access to read the entire story on my blog unless they subscribe and become members. I'd want readers to read only a few lines of the article before it fades with a CTA, similar to the fading text feature seen below.

What is the code of this fading text and CTA in the image.
[Click to view image][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2eLX.png)

Comment: And what did you tried yourself so far? :)

Comment: I tried using plugins like Paid Memberships Pro and content control but they don't have the fading text feature.

Comment: Hmmm... okay, and now what? What are you expecting? We love to help with problems, but this isn't a scripting service. So you do need to create something yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you do it in back-end then I suggest using ejs. You could then check if user is authenticated and depending on the answer render rest of your blog's content. And fading is just a simple css effect, probably **::before** with background image set to gradient from white to transparent.